# Numbers $n$ whose representation as the product of two divisors require more digits than that of $n$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, sequences-and-series, integer-sequences

**Note**: Posting in MO since it was [unanswered in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4383566/numbers-n-whose-representation-as-the-product-of-two-divisors-require-more-dig)

Let $f(x)$ be the number of digits in the decimal representation of $x$ e.g. $, f(0) = 1, f(1729) = 4$. If $n = ab$ then we can show that $f(ab) > f(a) + f(b)$ is impossible. Hence $f(ab)$ is either less than or equal to $f(a) + f(b)$. Loosely speaking if $f(ab) < f(a) + f(b)$, we are using more digits than the number itself hence the number of digits get inflated.

**Definition**: A number $n$ is said to be inflated if for all its divisors $n = ab$, we have $f(ab) < f(a) + f(b)$.

E.g. The divisors of $4321$ are $[1, 29, 149, 4321]$ and clearly $4321$ is wasteful. But $4324$ is not a wasteful number since $4324 = 46 \times 94$ and $f(4324) = f(46) + f(94) = 4$. Trivially, all primes $p$ are wasteful since $f(p \times 1) < f(p) + f(1)$. The first few inflated numbers are:

$$
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 17, 19, 22, 23, 26, 29, 31, 33, 34, 37, 38, 39, 41, 43, 44, 46, 47, 50, 51, 52, 53, 55, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99
$$

Graph for the density of wasteful numbers below $10^9$. There are $386000005$ wasteful numbers below $10^9$.

[image]

**Question 1**: In the comments of the posts in the [linked question in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4383566/numbers-n-whose-representation-as-the-product-of-two-divisors-require-more-dig), it as noted by different users that the sequence of inflated numbers appears to be same as [OEIS A122427](http://oeis.org/A122427). This is not immediately obvious because the two sequence seems to have different definitions. Are these two sequences identical?

**Question 2**: What are the necessary and sufficient conditions for a number to be an inflated number? Does the natural density of inflated numbers exist? Experimental data for $n \le 10^9$ suggests that it oscillates in a regular pattern between $0.2$ and $0.4$.

Comment: why isn't $1$ wasteful, $1=1\cdot 1$? I would suggest not to consider $1$ as a factor.

Comment: Suggestion for an additional question: can the product of two wasteful numbers that are not primes be wasteful?

Comment: Every wasteful number $n$ must be its own lexicographically greatest divisor: otherwise, given any divisor $a$, if $n=n_1n_2$ where $n_1$ is $f(a)$ digits and $n_2$ is $f(n)-f(a)$ digits, we have $n \ge 10^{f(n)-f(a)} n_1 \ge 10^{f(n)-f(a)} a$. Thus if $n=ab$, we have $f(b) \ge f(10^{f(n)-f(a)})=f(n)-f(a)+1$.

Comment: @ManfredWeis The answer to your question is yes. The smallest example is $4 \times 22 = 88$ and all these three are wasteful numbers

Answer (score 4):

The two sequences are indeed equal.

**Every wasteful number n must be its own lexicographically greatest divisor:** otherwise, given any divisor $a$, if $n=n_1n_2$ where $n_1$ is $f(a)$ digits and $n_2$ is $f(n)−f(a)$ digits, we have $n≥10^{f(n)−f(a)}n_1≥10^{f(n)−f(a)}a$. Thus if $n=ab$, we have $f(b)≥f(10^{f(n)−f(a)})=f(n)−f(a)+1$.

**If $n=ab$ and $f(n)\le f(a)+f(b)$, then $a$ or $b$ is greater than $n$ lexicographically:** Write $a=x \times 10^{f(a)-1}$ and $b=y \times 10^{f(b)-1}$. For any two real numbers $x,y \in [1,10)$, we have $1 \le xy < 100$, so $f(\lfloor xy \rfloor) \in \{1,2\}$. In particular, $xy$ is lexicographically greater than or equal to $\max\{x,y\}$ if and only if $f(xy)=1$ (since $\max\{x,y\} \le xy < \min\{10x,10y\}$). Thus, we have $f(ab)\in \{f(a)+f(b),f(a)+f(b)-1\}$, and if $f(ab)=f(a)+f(b)$, then either $a$ or $b$ is greater than $n$ lexicographically. Thus, the two sequences are equal.